# My website is not shown up in google search http://www.refillwallet.com

Tags: web, google-search

It's strange for me, I have a [website](http://www.refillwallet.com).

Which is live from more than 4 months. But still if i search for the domain "refillwallet" on google search. I don't see my website in search results. Where else same this is working in Bing search and Yahoo search perfectly fine.

Please help me rectifying this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is not related to programming. You can contact google support for why their crawlers are not able to get your site. There is a detailed procedure to address such issues.

Comment: search on how to add website to google search engine.

Comment: research how to do search engine optimization. this is a good place to start https://moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO instead of directly about programming.

Answer (score 0):

Check your robots.txt file, it might work against Google and another option is to add it manually to search console.
**Edit**
Its currently on Google.